# Android - Facebook Analytics App Install Event not triggered

Tags: android, ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-insights

Am using **Facebook SDK 3.21 for Android** and **Facebook SDK 3.23 for iOS**, and I have an App ID & App Link url.

Now my questions are:
**1.** Is App Install event counts for each fresh install to the same device.?
(By fresh install I mean installed once, launched the app & uninstalled it. Again installed and so on)

**2.** I tried fresh installations for 3 devices; Galaxy S4, Galaxy A7 & Moto X. The App Install event is not getting counted for Galaxy A7 (not listed in filter options). And If I freshly install it again to 2 other devices, the app install count is not getting updated. So is there any special case like for a device only once the app install event is counted? But in case of iOS app, fresh installations are counted as each App Install events, and so the count keeps updating. But iOS device models are not listed in filter options. (During upgrade installation, the app install is not counted which is expected)

**Android code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, FB_APP_ID);
    Settings.sdkInitialize(this);
    Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    }
    ........
}
```

**iOS code:**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{  
    [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:FB_APP_ID];
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

**3.** Now in Android, if I use the AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, FB_APP_ID); in onResume() function (as per documentation), and Settings.sdkInitialize(this); in onCreate() function, the App Install count is not updated for fresh installs but Inbound AppLinks count updates(on clicking App Link shared in Facebook). Now if i remove the Settings.sdkInitialize(); from onCreate(), the App Install counts but not the Inbound AppLink event. I can't figure out whats happening here.

**4.** Can we track the Installations done via App Link(doesn't include installations directly from play store)? Is there any event for that.? What I came into conclusion is that, Mobile Ads Installs could be tracked but not via App Link(If am wrong please correct me).

Final note, the AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, FB_APP_ID); updates the App Launch events as expected and i haven't used AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this, FB_APP_ID); as I don't want any session events.

I'am out of my mind, any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: For iOS, are you able to use the advertiser ID? If you can't use the advertiser ID, then there's no way for FB to dedupe across an uninstall/reinstall case, which is probably why you're seeing multiple installs in that case.

Comment: Thanks Ming. Let me check this case with my iOS app.

Comment: @Ming: What about other scenarios in my question. If am not wrong, I think facebook analytics is still in progress.. There were few changes in analytics from last week onwards..

Comment: Installs should only count once per device, unless FB doesn't know about your device (like when there's no IDFA). Inbound app links are different than installs. They're logged every time an app link opens your app.

Comment: Thanks Ming.. Regarding my second question.. for some devices the device modals are listing, but for some other the install count is incremented but the device modal is not listed in the filter option.. Is there any specific reason for this.?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with how that feature works.

Comment: Ok Ming... Thanks for ur comments...