# Android - Will Facebook App Install event count's fresh installation more than once to same device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-insights

How the Facebook App Install event is counted.? What if the application is installed to same device more than once(as fresh install and not upgrading)? Will the count gets incremented.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it will count as 1.

Comment: Thanks Ming, so I hope installing to same device more than once is handled by facebook. Well I got a scenario, I tried installing the android app more than 1's and it counted only 1 installation (the initial install). But when i tried installing iOS app more than 1's and it counted each install.

Comment: @Ming: could you please figure out this issue. [Android - Facebook Analytics App Install Event not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887161/android-facebook-analytics-app-install-event-not-triggered) .. Thanks in advance.